# How to use Android Design Pack provided by Google with Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, user-interface

I am trying to use these cool set of add-ins that Google provides in the link below

http://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html

But I cannot understand how to integrate it with eclipse so that they are available directly as a drag and drop. Do you have any idea how to use it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot integrate into eclipse, because it only allows valid [Views](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) "linked" to your project (directly or from a library). These are just sources to make drawables. You have to create your own drawables from it. But if you're interested in holo theme, you should check the sources of android (API 11+). If you've installed, you can find it at /platforms/android-11/data/res/ . Maybe you find useful the [HoloEverywhere](https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere) project. But you can use the Action Bar Icon Pack, you have to copy the appropriate drawables to your project and when you drag an ImageView into the layout editor, you can choose the source from a dialog or you can enter path in xml.

**EDIT**
Forgot to mention, there is a very great online tool which will generate holo drawables with custom colors [here](http://android-holo-colors.com/).

Answer (score 1):

After some digging up and watching Google IO 2012 videos on Design, the Design pack is actually a template for designers to create a UI before actually developing it. It contains a pack of action bar icons (These can be imported into your project), bunch of stencils that can be used with Adobe products to create an initial mock ups of your applications. Though, they cannot be directly imported into eclipse and used (as they are actually available already with the SDK), its a good guide to start design instead of actually coding and re-inventing afterwards.

Comment: Actually, it is a good practice to include those icons into the project (into /res/drawable-XXdpi/). In that way, your design won't change from one Android version to another.